# Lua not not the same as not not

Tags: lua

I was using some coroutines and was trying to resume one using not:

```
if not co == nil then `resume end
```

and the coroutine wouldn't resume. Though co was nil. It was baffling.

So I eventually tried

```
if co then `resume end
```

and it worked!

why isn't not (nil == nil), which is logically false when co is nil and true when it is not which is not the same as as nil which is logically false when co is nil and true otherwise?

I use not all the time to negate the logical expression but now I'm worried that maybe some of my code is buggy. Maybe this only has a problem with coroutines? (and I'm 100% sure that the value is nil, because that is what is printed out, unless nil no longer equals nil)

Comment: if you imply that co is a thread or nil otherwise you can simply write `if co then resume end`. There is no need to check if co equals nil explicitly. If you want to be 100% sure check if type(co) equals "thread".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`not co == nil` is equivalent to `(not co) == nil` because of [operator  precedence](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.8).

If `co` is nil, then `not co` is true and so different from nil.

In fact, the result of `not` is always true or false, and so never equal to nil.

Write `not (co == nil)` or `co ~= nil`.

Comment: wow, ok, that is strange ;/ not is just an inverter then, it shouldn't be that way, but oh well...

Comment: @AbstractDissonance why shouldn't it be that way? that's like saying that something Italians say is strange and that it shouldn't be that way, just because you don't know Italian grammar...

Comment: @AbstractDissonance, it's the same in other languages. For instance, in C, `! x == 2` is not equivalent to `!(x == 2)`.

Comment: @Piglet Sheesh, because not applies to a boolean expression, not x is not necessary a boolean expression but not (boolean) is always works. This isn't italian and not a natural language. Stop fishing.  what is not 3? it makes no sense logically. One can define not to be whatever they want... but it doesn't mean it is logical. Both not and ! should work on an expression, not a variable because they are operators in boolean algebra, not operators of types(unless those types are boolean, of course).

Comment: Just because some one does something wrong doesn't mean it becomes right.  You can define anything to be anything, but that doesn't make it logical or meaningful. In this case, it is meaningful but not logical. Not is a logical operator and has always been and therefor that is the most natural way to interpret it. If you are a mathematician, physicist, or logician, you will think of it that way. Basically one treats if not x as 'ifnot x' rather than if 'not x'. An ifnot is simply the negation of the corresponding if statement and is easily interpreted. Luas way produces ambiguity because it is

Comment: @AbstractDissonance It is never a good idea to make assumptions in programming languages. It is not ambiguous to anyone who read the first 3 reference manual chapters on the very basic rules of Lua carefully. there are very clear conventions. One of them is that all values but false and nil are logically true. So `not 3` makes perfect sense. It's false. You have to follow all of Lua's rules. You cannot just pick the ones that make sense to you for whatever reason.

Comment: If it helps, `not` is a projection operator with a domain of any value and a range of `true`, `false`. `and` and `or` are selection operators with a domain of any value × any value and a range of any value.